# Time difference between 2 datetime moment

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

SO i have 2 datetime objects .

```
now = Nov 15 4:00 PM
later = Nov 15 6:00PM
```

My objective is to get the total hours between (9AM to 5 PM) , given the now and later times.

resulting answer shud be 1 hour. (since im only concerned about time range that falls within 9AM-5PM)

```
now =  Nov 15 6:00 AM
later = Nov 15 8:00 PM
```

resulting answer should be 8 hours.

is the best way to achieve this using the diff function in moment and stripping the hour out and calculating individual use cases ( when start time less than 9AM/ start time greater than 9AM) . similarly end time (less than 5PM/greater than 5PM) etc?

Also how to tackle this case where,

```
now = Nov 15 9:00AM
later = Nov 18 2:00PM
```

resulting answer shud be ,

8(nov 15)+8(nov 16)+8(nov 17)+5(nov 18) = 29hrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working solution

```js
var now = moment("15 Nov 2016, 9:00:00 am", "DD MMM yyyy, h:mm:ss a").toDate();
var later = moment("18 Nov 2016, 2:00:00 pm", "DD MMM yyyy, h:mm:ss a").toDate();

function getWorkingHours(now, later) {
 var hoursToday = 0;

 var workingHourStart = 9;
 var workingHourEnd = 17;//5pm
 var workDuration = workingHourEnd - workingHourStart;
 
 if(workingHourEnd - getHours(now) > 0) {
  hoursToday = (workingHourEnd - getHours(now));
  hoursToday = (hoursToday > workDuration) ? workDuration : hoursToday;
 }

 var hoursLater = 0;

 if(getHours(later) - workingHourStart > 0) {
  hoursLater = (getHours(later) - workingHourStart);
  hoursLater = (hoursLater > workDuration) ? workDuration : hoursLater;
 }

 var actualDiffHours = (later.getTime() - now.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
 var actualHoursInBetween = actualDiffHours - (24 - getHours(now)) - getHours(later);

 var workingHoursInBetween = (actualHoursInBetween / 24) * 8;
 
 return hoursToday + workingHoursInBetween + hoursLater;
}

function getHours(date) {
 var hours = date.getHours() + date.getMinutes() / 60 + date.getSeconds() / 3600 + date.getMilliseconds() / 3600/1000;
 return hours;
}

console.log(getWorkingHours(now, later));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```js
const now = moment(new Date(2016, 11, 15, 9, 0, 0));
const then = moment(new Date(2016, 11, 18, 14, 0, 0));

function calDiff(now, then) {
  if (now.hour() < 9) {
    now.hour(9);
  }

  if (then.hour() > 17) {
    then.hour(17);
  }

  const total = then.diff(now, 'hours');

  const day = Math.floor(total / 24);
  
  return total - (16 * day);
}

console.log(calDiff(now, then));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complicated... Function getActiveHours calculates all active slots between start and finish dates, both inclusive, and then removes the missing hours at the beginning of the start date and at the end of the finish date.

```
var getDateObject = function (date) {
  if (date && date.constructor.name == "Array") {
    while (date.length < 7) {date.push(0);}
    date = new Date(date[0], date[1], date[2], date[3], date[4], date[5], date[6]);
  } else if (typeof date == 'string' || typeof date == 'number') {
    date = new Date(date);
  }
  return date;
};

var trimDate = function (date, period) {
  var periods = ['second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day'];
  period = periods.indexOf(period);
  if (typeof date != 'number') {date = getDateObject(date).getTime();}
  date = Math.floor(date/1000);
  if (period > 0) {date = Math.floor(date/60);}
  if (period > 1) {date = Math.floor(date/60);}
  if (period > 2) {date = Math.floor(date/24);}
  return new Date(date*24*60*60*1000);
};

var getOffset = function (date) {return getDateObject(date).getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;};

var addOffset = function (date) {
  date = getDateObject(date);
  return new Date(date.getTime()+getOffset(date));
};

var getActiveHours = function (iniDateTime, endDateTime, startHour, finishHour) {
  var hourMs = 60*60*1000; // Define daily active hours 0-24 (decimal 17.5 = 5:30pm):
  if (startHour == null) {startHour = 9;}
  if (finishHour == null) {finishHour = 17;}
  startHour *= hourMs; finishHour *= hourMs;
  iniDateTime = getDateObject(iniDateTime).getTime();
  endDateTime = getDateObject(endDateTime).getTime();
  var iniDayTime = addOffset(trimDate(iniDateTime, 'day')).getTime();
  var endDayTime = addOffset(trimDate(endDateTime, 'day')).getTime();
  var totalHoursMs = (endDayTime-iniDayTime+24*hourMs)*(finishHour-startHour)/hourMs/24;
  var iniHoursNotInMs = iniDateTime-iniDayTime-startHour;
  var endHoursNotInMs = endDayTime+finishHour-endDateTime;
  return (totalHoursMs-iniHoursNotInMs-endHoursNotInMs)/hourMs;
};

console.log(Math.round(getActiveHours('2016-09-13 11:45:38', '2016-09-15 15:30:25'))); // 20 // Use Math round or floor
```

Answer (score 0):

I had started writing this awhile back when I first saw the question, but got caught up. My answer is very similar to Khang's, but we went about a certain section of it a little differently.

The basic idea behind the code is that it takes two moment objects. If the start hours are less than nine, we set them to be nine, and if the end hours are greater than 17 (5pm) we set them to be 17.

Next we get the difference between the two objects in days. For each day we know that there are 8 hours the person can get credit for. I then move the date of the start day to the end day, and take the hours between them.

The idea behind this is that if both times are within the same days, there will be 0 days difference. If it is 1, then we will get a total of 8 hours regardless where we start in the day. the only cases I haven't tested are things where the start time is greater than the end time (I'll test it ASAP and make an edit if there's anything I need to change)

## Edit

there was indeed a problem if the start time was after the end time (the hours).
This was fixed by adding in one if statement.

```js
$(function() {
  function getActiveHours(start, end) {
    if (start.hours() < 9) start.hours(9);
    if (end.hours() > 17) end.hours(17);
    //These two if's should remove most of the issues when we are doing basic work
    var days = end.diff(start, 'days');
    if (days == 0 && (end.date() - start.date()) == 1) days = 1;
    var hours = (days * 8); //gets the hours
    start.date(end.date());
    var diff = end.diff(start, 'hours');
    return hours + diff;
  }
  var start = moment([2016, 10, 15, 9, 0, 0]);
  var end = moment([2016, 10, 18, 14, 0, 0]);

  $('#results').html('Total hours worked from ' + start.format('MM-DD-YYYY @ hh:mm:ss') + ' to ' + end.format('MM-DD-YYYY @ hh:mm:ss') + ' is ' + getActiveHours(start, end))

});
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```